# Incoherent handling of coordinates in basemap addcyclic

Tags: python, netcdf, matplotlib-basemap

I have used all `mpl_toolkits.basemap` functions successfully on several global GCM netcdf datasets. Until I met this grid, with longitudes starting at 0.9375 (instead of 0 as I have always seen) and ending at 359.062.

To prepare a plot, I need to:

1. make the plot continuous with:

   ```
   # input_var is a 2D numpy array
   var_cyclicDUMMY, lons_cyclicDUMMY = addcyclic(input_var, lons)
   ```

   I thus obtain a 2D array `var_cyclicDUMMYwith` an extra column (one extra longitude), and a 1D array `lons_cyclicDUMMY` with one extra element at the end, i.e. one extra longitude, but at 0.9375, instead of the 360 that is needed.
   Indeed in the next step, where I
2. shift the grid, so longitudes go from -180 to 180 instead of 0 to 360, with:

   ```
   var_cyclic, lons_cyclic = shiftgrid(180., var_cyclicDUMMY, 
                                       lons_cyclicDUMMY, start=False)
   ```

   I get an `ValueError: lon0 outside of range of lonsin`

Any suggestions how to get around this with basemap or another solution?

Comment: It appears to work correctly, if you reverse the order of the operators, i.e. first `shiftgrid` and then `addcyclic`.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work that way either.